# How to get only the year as a dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set the column year as the index of my dataframe, but I could not figure out how to get only the year as the index, it also shows the month and day:

```
d = {'Year': ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'], 'Sales': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df.set_index('Year')

df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)

df2  #index also shows month and day here
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: A datetime object will always contain all date fields. You'll need a string for that, as you initially have

Comment: You don't need this `df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)`. Before this you will get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work? Remove the `to_datetime()` conversion:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Year': ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'], 'Sales': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df.set_index('Year')

#df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)

df2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: Use the [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors) accessor and access the [year](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-dt) property

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Year': ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'], 'Sales': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = df.set_index('Year')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.year
print(df2)

# output
     Sales
Year      
2016   100
2017   200
2018   300
2019   400
2020   500
```